# auto width for selectonemenu panel

Tags: css

I'm having some problem to get the css work. I do not want the horizontal scrollbar to appear at the panel. Is there a way to make the panel width auto without setting a fixed width? I am using p:selectOneMenu in xhtml.

[image: selectonemenu-panel]

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    width: 158px !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel {
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question(HTML?). It is unclear what the issue is.

Comment: @Stratus3D I have added in a screenshot and some more info

Comment: `Is there a way to make the panel width auto without setting a fixed width?` If you don't set a width then the width is auto

Comment: @Huangism But I don't want the horizontal scrollbar to appear. Is there any way?

Comment: @bittersour you can try `overflow-x: hidden;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x

Comment: @Huangism I have tried that before. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @bittersour then you should definitely post the code you tried and see if we can help you. Post the code using overflow-x that did not work for you

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper {
     overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

I had the same problem, fixed it this way.

Answer (score 0):

All block level elements are width:auto by default;

I can't be sure this will work without jsfiddle link, but try this:

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around this problem by adding the following rule:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-list {
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

The highlighted item might not be completely covered in this case but it's better than scrolling IMO.

#### Edit

If you never want a horizontal scroll bar then the following fixes the problem nicely for me (highlighting too):

```
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list-item {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```